# Textbox with special format not update to Datagridview with binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a **Datagridview** and **Textbox**. Datagridview have column '**PublishYear**
' with type number only.
I'm binding that column to Textbox as bellow:

```
txtPublishYear.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataGridview.DataSource, "PublishYear", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "", $"Năm {0}");
```

Textbox listen data of Datagridview working. But I can't update data of grid when text of Textbox change. How can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The grid will not update as the `TextBox` changes. The grid will only update when the editing session is finalised, which will happen automatically when you navigate to a different record. If you're using a `BindingSource` then you can call `EndEdit` on that to force it.

Comment: Thank @John . I have been solution. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**
...

```
Binding bd = txtPublishYear.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataGridview.DataSource, "PublishYear", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "", $"Năm {0}");
bd.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(CurrencyStringToNumber);
```

...

```
private void CurrencyStringToNumber(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
        {
            if (cevent.DesiredType != typeof(Int16)) return;

            string result = Regex.Match(txtPublishYear.Text, @"\d+").Value;
            cevent.Value = int.Parse(result,NumberStyles.Currency, null);
        }
```